# How to add css in laravel manually?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to add my css in laravel manually without using command. I save my folder **css** to **public** and use this code

```
{!! Html::style( asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')) !!}
{!! Html::style( asset('css/style.css')) !!}
```

but still doesn't work. I read tutorials about this but they teach to cammand it. Do I have something to configure about this? I'm new in laravel. Trying to learn it.
hoping for your help. thanks in advance

Comment: What does not work? What it the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: thanks man. This only work in public folder right? I found out here there is resources folder then assets folder.

Comment: Yes, only public folder.

Comment: i will take this an answer. 7 mins left

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ HTML::style('sximo/themes/sximone/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}
```

Comment: I'm confuse here. I put it directly to my page. I get an error. sorry

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Request::root(); ?>/protected/public/css/angular-chart.min.css">